# In C# how can i use the || operand in an if statement where im looking for 2 files?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm getting the error "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'" when I use the below statement.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\file1.exe") || (@"c:\file2.exe"))
  {
     do something
  }
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This won't work because `File.Exists` only takes a string as a parameter. You are not passing a string to it. Something like this *could* work if you wrote your own function that took a list of strings as parameters, then checked to see if any of them existed.

Comment: I remember I did this a few times, I cant remember where I picked up the habbit of doing it though, for example I would do.

if (Number == 10 || 11) { }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost had it...

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\file1.exe") || File.Exists(@"c:\file2.exe"))
{
   //do something
}
```

In an `if` statement, if you want to use `||` you need to make sure you treat them as separate pieces of a statement.

In this case, the compiler would have no way to "guess" that you are wanting to know if a file exists on your right-hand statement, you need to be explicit with it.

Just like if you want to check to see if a person's age is less than 20 but greater than 18, you would do the following:

```
if (age < 20 && age > 18) {}
```

You can't just say `age < 20 || 18` because you could be talking about anything, not just age.  What if you wanted weight or height as the second check?  C# won't be able to guess for you.

Comment: Doh! Man I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure thing.  I've made that mistake before as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\file1.exe") || File.Exists(@"c:\file2.exe"))
  {
     // do something
  }
```

`File.Exists` returns a `bool` (i.e. true or false), so you have to call it on each path.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
(File.Exists(@"C:\file1.exe") || (File.Exists(@"c:\file2.exe"))
```